# Нормально ли вешать один и тот же обработчик несколько раз?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В примере ниже обработчик на кнопку закрытия блока вешается каждый раз при открытии блока, нормальна ли такая практика?
Что происходит за кулисами: обработчики события накладываются друг на друга, как интервалы при неоднократном вызове?
Или обработчики заменяют друг друга при каждом открытии блока?
P.S. знаю, что в примере обработчик можно повесить всего один раз сразу, но интересует именно изложенный ниже подход.

```js
$('.open').on('click', function () {
    $('div').show();
    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        $('div').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
div{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open">открыть</button>
<div>
   <span> блок открыт </span>
   <button class="close">закрыть </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Не забываем про `off`. Иначе будет океан незавершенных событий.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ссылки обработчики будут добавляться многократно.

Добавьте вывод в консоль в обработчике и сами все увидите:

```js
var count = 0;
$('.open').on('click', function () {
    $('div.a').show();
    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        console.log(count++)
        $('div.a').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
div.a{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open">открыть</button>
<div class="a">
   <span> блок открыт </span>
   <button class="close">закрыть </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Почти все верно, но какой смысл одной функции в другой...???

Вот так лучше

```js
var count = 0;
$('.open').on('click', function() {
  $('div.a').show();
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  console.log(count++)
  $('div.a').hide();
});
```

```css
div.a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open">открыть</button>
<div class="a">
  <span> блок открыт </span>
  <button class="close">закрыть </button>
</div>
```

Comment: смысл в том, что подписка на событие `close` происходит только после `open`. Возможно у автора есть кнопка `close`, но если на нее нажать то ничего не произойдет, до тех пор пока не нажмется `open`. А вы немного поменяли логику в своем коде

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, в данном примере нет ни какого смысла...

Comment: автор мог выбрать данный пример для абстракта...я думаю реальный пример может быть намного сложнее. Ну и вопрос совсем не об этом. Если речь идет о коде именно такого вида, как предоставил автор в вопросе, то вы правы, и даже нужно было бы написать как у вас.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, Автор только учиться, сомневаюсь, что у него какой-то сложный пример из контекста которого вырван этот кусок кода...

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц вы абсолютно правы код был для абстракта, на деле с кнопки «закрыть/открыть» выполнят более сложные задачи, чем в примере

Comment: @Air кнопки в реальном коде выполняют более сложные задачи чем открыть/закрыть, поэтому необходим именно такой вариант + я пометил в P.S. что знаю вами предложенный вариант